# add column based on multiple conditions with mutate() in tidy R grep

Tags: r, tidyr

I am working to classify a wide data frame in an added column, but based on the threshold (>0) of multiple columns. Previous examples here on SO require complete names of columns and if else() statements with > and ==. But I need to be able to use grep() or contains() to isolate columns based on a common string.

Input dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
    "ID" = c("asdf","vfdkun", "seifu", "seijd", "qweri"),
    "elephant_zoo" = c(1,1,1,2,0), #Should not be useful there
    "rhino_zoo" = c(1,2,3,1,0), #Should not be useful there
    "hippo_zoo" = c(1,1,0,0,0),
    "elephant_wild_A" = c(0,0,1,1,3),
    "rhino_wild_A" = c(0,0,4,3,1),
    "elephant_wild_B" = c(0,0,0,0,0),
    "rhino_wild_C" = c(0,0,1,5,7),
    "hippo_wild_B" = c(0,0,0,0,0)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var = "ID")
df
```

> In reality, this has many many more columns and rows!

**Desired output dataframe** has classified rows (`ZOO` and `WILD`) and a compilation of these `CLASSIFICATION`.

```
df_goal <- data.frame(
    "ID" = c("asdf","vfdkun", "seifu", "seijd", "qweri"),
    "elephant_zoo" = c(1,1,1,2,2), #Should not be useful there
    "rhino_zoo" = c(1,2,3,1,2), #Should not be useful there
    "hippo_zoo" = c(1,1,0,0,2),
    "elephant_wild_A" = c(0,0,1,1,3),
    "rhino_wild_A" = c(1,0,4,3,1),
    "elephant_wild_B" = c(0,0,0,0,0),
    "rhino_wild_C" = c(6,0,1,5,7),
    "hippo_wild_B" = c(0,0,0,0,0)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var = "ID") %>% 
    add_column(ZOO = c("zoo", "zoo", "zoo", "zoo", "")) %>% 
    add_column(WILD = c("", "", "wild", "wild", "wild")) %>% 
    add_column(CLASSIFICATION = c("zoo only", "zoo only", "both", "both", "wild only"))
df_goal
```

I am hoping to use a combination of `mutate()` and `case_when()`, but I cannot get the select of multiple columns correct.
Examples of attempts:

```
# using an if else statement
df %>%
   mutate(ZOO = ifelse(select(contains("zoo")) > 0, "zoo", "F"))

# using mutate and case_when
df %>%
   mutate(ZOO = case_when(
       select(contains("zoo")) > 0 ~ "zoo",
       TRUE ~ ""))
```

**My actual** data frame has many more categories, so being able to break it down into the ZOO vs WILD and then following up with the compiled column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `reduce` from `purrr` package. One may use an intermediate function `any_cols` to made the code clearer and use it with `across`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
any_cols <- function(df) reduce(df, `|`)
df %>%
    mutate(ZOO = ifelse(any_cols(across(contains("zoo"), ~`>`(.,0))), "zoo", "F"))
  elephant_zoo rhino_zoo hippo_zoo elephant_wild_A rhino_wild_A elephant_wild_B rhino_wild_C hippo_wild_B ZOO
1            1         1         1               0            0               0            0            0 zoo
2            1         2         1               0            0               0            0            0 zoo
3            1         3         0               1            4               0            1            0 zoo
4            2         1         0               1            3               0            5            0 zoo
5            0         0         0               3            1               0            7            0   F

df %>%
    mutate(ZOO = 
             case_when(any_cols(across(contains("zoo"), ~`>`(.,0))) ~ "zoo", 
                       TRUE ~ "F"))
  elephant_zoo rhino_zoo hippo_zoo elephant_wild_A rhino_wild_A elephant_wild_B rhino_wild_C hippo_wild_B ZOO
1            1         1         1               0            0               0            0            0 zoo
2            1         2         1               0            0               0            0            0 zoo
3            1         3         0               1            4               0            1            0 zoo
4            2         1         0               1            3               0            5            0 zoo
5            0         0         0               3            1               0            7            0   F
```